# Geodesics of hyperbolic plane

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

I just found (or: I think that I found) the geodesics of the upper, closed half plane of $\mathbb R^2$. To verify my solution: Is it correct that the geodesics are the circles and lines which meet the unit circle at right angles?

Thanks a lot for the confirmation (or the correction, if I'm wrong...)

Edit: Here is what I have so far (this should be correct, isn't it?):

[image: This should be correct, isn't it?]

Comment: might you include your calculations? so it is easier for us to analyze if your solution is correct?

Comment: Do you mean the poincare disk instead of upper half plane? Or maybe you mean "x-axis" instead of "unit circle". In the upper half plane, there are lots of geodesics which don't meet the unit circle at all.  And lots that meet it non-orthogonally.  For each point and each tangent vector at that point there should be a unique geodesic.  If what you said were true, there would only be one geodesic passing through any particular point on the unit circle

Comment: I included my calculations and edited the question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It is not correct that the geodesics of the upper half plane $\mathbb{H}=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:\;y>0\}$ with metric $g$ given by $g_{xx}=g_{yy}=1/y^2$ and $g_{xy}=g_{yx}=0$ the circles and lines which meet the unit circle at right angles. Instead, they are the circles and lines that meet the $x$-axis (the line $y=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$) at right angles.

A curve  $\gamma:I\subset\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{H}:s\mapsto(x_1(s),x_2(s))$ is a geodesic if it satisfies the geodesic equation:
\begin{equation}
  \frac{d^2x_k}{ds^2} + 
  \sum_{i,j=1}^2\Gamma^k_{ij}\frac{dx_i}{ds}\frac{dx_j}{ds}=0,
\end{equation}
for $k=1,2$ and where $\Gamma^k_{ij}$ are the Christoffel symbols, which in this case are
\begin{equation}
\Gamma^1_{12}=\Gamma^1_{21}=\Gamma^2_{22}=-1/y;\;\;
\Gamma^2_{11}=1/y;\;\;\;
\Gamma^1_{11}=\Gamma^2_{12}=\Gamma^2_{21}=\Gamma^1_{22}=0.
\end{equation}
The geodesic equations are then the following system of differential equations (writing $x=x_1$ and $y=x_2$):
\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2x}{ds^2}-2\frac{1}{y}\frac{dx}{ds}\frac{dy}{ds}=0;\;\;\;
\frac{d^2y}{ds^2}+\frac{1}{y}
\left[\left(\frac{dx}{ds}\right)^2-\left(\frac{dy}{ds}\right)^2\right]=0
\end{equation}
For $\frac{dx}{ds}\neq 0$ the solutions satisfy: $x^2+y^2-ax=b$, where $a$ and $b$ are constants. Those are circles with center in the line $y=0$, and thus meeting that line at right angles. The solutions for $\frac{dx}{ds}=0$ are just vertical lines.

Comment: should the geodesic equation be $\dfrac {d^{2}x}{ds^{2}}-\dfrac {2}{y}\dfrac {dx}{ds}\dfrac {dy}{ds}=0$; $\dfrac {dy^{2}}{ds^{2}}+\dfrac {1}{y}\left( \left( \dfrac {dx}{ds}\right) ^{2}-\left( \dfrac {dy}{ds}\right) ^{2}\right) =0$? And I find some difficulties solving it.

Comment: @user360777 It should, thanks! That was a typo, I have corrected it in the answer

Comment: @user360777 To solve it, the non-trivial case is $\dfrac{dx}{ds}\neq0$. A relatively easy approach is to take the derivative of $y\dfrac{dy}{ds}\left(\dfrac{dx}{ds}\right)^{-1}-x$ and notice that it should vanish by substitution of both differential equations. Then, $x\dfrac{dx}{ds}+y\dfrac{dy}{ds}=(constant)\cdot\dfrac{dx}{ds}$, and that's just the derivative of the equation of a circle around a point at $y=0$

Comment: Thanks! the vanishing term should be the derivative of $y\dfrac{dy}{ds}\left(\dfrac{dx}{ds}\right)^{-1}+x$ in your answer. it's hard for many people to come up with this smart idea without knowing the geodesics before

Answer (score 11):

Here I provide an alternative solution based on a physicist's convention.

In mathematical physics concerning differential geometry, e.g. general relativity, one often uses [Killing vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killing_vector_field) to help solving a geodesic. Each Killing vector $K$ gives a first integral ([Einstein summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation) assumed)
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d} x^i}{\mathrm{d} \lambda} K_i = \text{const.},
$$
so that one can deal with a set of $n_K$ *first-order* differential equations, instead of the *second-order* and often non-linear equations, if the number of Killing vectors is $n_K$.

In your case, all the Killing vectors in [Poincaré half-plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_half-plane_model) are [given by](https://www.imprs-mis.mpg.de/fileadmin/imprs/ringvorlesung-2015_mpi-mis_homework.pdf)
$$
T = \partial_1,\qquad
D = 2\left(x\,\partial_x+y\,\partial_y\right),\qquad
S = (y^2-x^2)\,\partial_x - 2xy\,\partial_y.
$$
Their [musical isomorphisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism) $g(K,\cdot)$ are
$$
T^{\flat} = \frac{1}{y^2}\mathrm{d}x,\qquad
D^{\flat} = \frac{2}{y^2}\left(x\,\mathrm{d}x+y\,\mathrm{d}y\right),\qquad
S^{\flat} = \left(1-\frac{x^2}{y^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x - 2\frac{x}{y}\,\mathrm{d}y.
$$
One has therefore three first integrals
$$
t = \frac{\mathrm{d}x^i}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} T_i = \frac{1}{y^2} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\lambda},\\
d = \frac{\mathrm{d}x^i}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} D_i = \frac{2}{y^2} \left( x \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} + y \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}\right), \\
s = \frac{\mathrm{d}x^i}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} S_i = \left(1-\frac{x^2}{y^2}\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}\lambda} - 2\frac{x}{y} \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}\lambda}.
$$

In this case, which is named as a maximally symmetric space in physics, the number of equations $n_K = N(N+1)/2 = 3$ is already larger than that of variables $N = 2$. *Algebraic* elimination gives
$$
(x^2 + y^2)t - x d - s = 0,
$$
which is essentially the same as [coconut](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/391996/coconut)'s [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2057021).

An additional advantage of this method is, Killing vectors are realisation of symmetries, so that each integration constant now has a geometric meaning. Unfortunately as a physicist I am not able to express the meaning in mathematical terms.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to write down the solution in full parametric form. It is parametrized with the intial conditions: $x(0)=x_0$, $y(0)=y_0$, $x'(0)=u_0$,
$y'(0)=v_0$ and additionally the constraint $u_0^2+v_0^2=y_0^2$ is implied.

For the circle:

$x(\lambda) = x_0+\frac{u_0 y_0\sinh\lambda}{y_0\cosh\lambda-v_0\sinh\lambda}$

$y(\lambda)=\frac{y_0^2}{|y_0\cosh\lambda-v_0\sinh\lambda|}$

For $u_0=0$ it follows that $v_0=y_0$ and the straight line is recovered from the general solution:

$x(\lambda)=x_0$

$y(\lambda)=y_0 \exp(\lambda)$

Comment: 1. The vertical line has already been included in the former expression with $u_0 = 0$, so that $v_0 = \pm 1$ according to your constraint.

2. It might make better sense with $y'(0) = w_0$ and the constraint $(u_0^2 - w_0^2)/y_0^2 = 1$, so that the velocity vector has length $1$ with the hyperbolic metric. This is related to your convention with $v_0^2 = 1 + w_0^2 - y_0^2$.

Comment: Yes, that's correct, I edited the post accordingly. However, the metric has positive signature, so its $(u_0^2+v_0^2)/y_0^2=1$.